# Find lowest odd number in a loop

Tags: java

I know this code is wrong. I'm a beginner so bear with me.

I need to find the lowest odd number but it keeps coming up as zero no matter what numbers are entered. I need to initialize 'lowest' but how/where do I initialize it?

lowest = 0 is causing a problem but I'm not sure where to initialize lowest

```
class Odd

{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int number; //the number entered by the user
        int input; //the amount of numbers to be entered by the user
        int index;
        int lowest = 0; //lowest odd number

        System.out.println("How many numbers? ");
        input = EasyIn.getInt();

    for (index = 1; index <= input ; index ++) 
        {
            System.out.println("Enter number " + index + ":" );
            number = EasyIn.getInt();

            if ((number % 2 == 1) && (number < lowest)) 
            {
                lowest = number;    
            }

        }

    System.out.println("The lowest odd number entered was " + lowest);

    }
}
```

Comment: `int lowest = 0; //lowest odd number`. Note that 0 is not an odd number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're sure your input isn't empty, a solution is to initialize `lowest` to a [big enough value](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) :

```
int lowest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

This ways all values will be smaller, so `lowest` will be one of the values of your input.

Answer (score 4):

You are starting at `0` so you will not get a value larger.  If you start like this

```
int lowest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

Also (n % 2) will only be 1 for positive numbers. If you want to test for odd negative numbers you want `(n & 1) != 0`

---

Note: Integer.MAX_VALUE is an odd number so even if this is the only value it will be the maximum.  However, if you want to be able to tell the difference between some one entering this value and no odd values you can use this instead.

```
long lowest = Long.MAX_VALUE;
```

This will allow you to tell the difference between Integer.MAX_VALUE being entered and no value as Long.MAX_VALUE is much higher.

Comment: +1 to point out that `n%2 == 1` will only work for positive numbers. `n%2 != 0` can also be a workaround.

Comment: The n % 2 == 1 thing makes this answer (currently) the best one here and the only really complete one.  Not sure why the OP hasn't accepted it.

Answer (score 1):

You initialise lowest as 0 and then look for numbers lower than it (and odd).

I'd initialise it as EasyIn.getInt() so it's the first number in your list to check through.